# How to serve static html files through express without explicit rendering

Tags: node.js, express

I have around 20+ HTML files. I would like to render them, when requested as `host/filename.html`, without having to use `response.render` for each file. If I simply move my views folder in public folder (and set `views` of `express` accordingly), the browser is not rendering these HTMLs. Rather, I see the code on the screen. Can someone please advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this:

```
'/someRoute': (req, res, next) => {
        res.status(200).sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/index.html');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I was just wondering if it could work without explict rendering

Comment: I'm sorry but not so sure that you can do that.